# Java: read huge XML online, entry by entry

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

I am working with a huge XML file (wikipedia dump) and it certainly couldn't be read into a memory at once nor will it be practical to do so.

I googled SAX XML tutorials, but they all showing quite an ugly low-level approach, where you have to set flags manually and track what element you are in now.

Actually the whole dump consists of many relatively small *page* entries and a reasonable strategy looks like:

- read the whole page entry into memory;
- process it;
- dispose it and move to the next.

It would require only the amount of memory to handle single *page entry*, while I could use all the conveniencies of parsed tree-like XML representation.

**My questions are:**

- Is it possible to implement such a strategy in Java?
- Is it possible to do so using *Jsoup* as it is my main tool for working with smaller XML files?

Comment: Have you looked at StAX? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html

Comment: @JonSkeet Not yet, but I definitely will.

Comment: Using JAXB you are able to use stax as streaming code and then process parts of your XML using JAXB.